# manipulate linestyle in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to include a legend in my plot, which shows all lines as solid line even if the corresponding curve uses linstyle '--'. Is there

```
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='--')
plt.legend(loc=0) 
plt.show()
```

So the legend for the plot above should show one solid line.

Comment: search the matplotlib documentation for "proxy artist"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly [tell](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) `ax.legend` what to show and what not. Using a separate `Line2D` object (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html)) you can make the line in the legend solid even though the plotted line is dashed. Here is a working example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x,y,'r--')
line = Line2D([0,1],[0,1],linestyle='-', color='r')

ax.legend([line],['solid line'])

plt.show()
```

and the result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add a dummy entry to the plot :

```
dummy, = plt.plot(x[0], y[0], color='black', linestyle='solid')
```

and then add `dummy` to your legend.

Answer (score 0):

```
leg = plt.legend(loc=0) 
for line in leg.get_lines():
    line.set_linestyle('-')
```